# Can we Predict the Trajectory of a hypersonic missile?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag, aerodynamics, rocket-science

I read in a newspaper that we can't predict the trajectory of a hypersonic missile and that this property renders the missile undetectable.

However, what I could not understand is why can't we predict it's trajectory? What factors do we have to look at for predicting the trajectory of such high speed missiles?  Is this feature associated with its speed? I know that there would be forces like the thrust from propulsion, gravity, and the drag force. Is there anything else affecting the trajectory?

Comment: Never **EVER** trust a scientific or engineering statement found in a newspaper or 'public' magazine.

Answer (score 3):

I'll deal here with "classic" hypersonic missiles which travel through the upper reaches of the atmosphere and stay aloft by generating lift and operate under continuous thrust.

Such missiles are maneuverable, unlike ballistic missiles whose post-boost phase coasting trajectories can be mapped in real time and for which precise intercept courses can therefore be plotted. This means that when a defensive missile launch against a hypersonic missile is detected, it can quickly change course in response and avoid the incoming missile. It is in this sense that the hypersonic missile's trajectory is "unpredictable".

Also note this does not mean it is "undetectable"; it just means it is much harder to shoot down than a ballistic missile.

Comment: Just for the reference. In principle one hypersonic missile can be knocked down by a defensive hypersonic missile, depending on which missile's algo will be better. Thus at least in theory hypersonic missile is not completely undetectable.

Comment: "hypersonic" and "ballistic" are orthogonal.   While I agree that a hypersonic missile in ballistic phase will quickly drop to subsonic, It's important to clarify this;  further, a hypersonic missile with no active steering is essentially ballistic even if the engine is still providing thrust.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the missile's trajectory is predictable if you know everything about its thrust, position, and momentum at all times since its launch. The problem is that someone who launches a hypersonic missile generally does not inform the opposing missile defense systems, "Hey, I launched a missile at this time and place, and here is its full thrust profile and flight plan!" Generally, that is information that someone launching a missile does **not** want their target to know.

So these parameters must be *measured* by the missile defense system. The problem with hypersonic missiles is that these measurements are hard to make, for three main reasons:

1. Unlike an ICBM, which travels a roughly parabolic trajectory, a hypersonic missile can change course mid-flight. This means that information that was valid a few seconds ago may no longer be valid now.
2. Unlike an ICBM, which goes briefly into space, a hypersonic missile spends its time flying at low altitude, below the radar horizon, so accurate measurements aren't possible until it's much closer.
3. Unlike an ICBM, which generally spends some time in a near vacuum where it's the only radar-reflecting object around, a hypersonic missile heats the surrounding atmosphere into plasma. Plasma *absorbs* radio rather than reflecting it, which makes it much harder to bounce a radar pulse off of it.

Comment: can't other em waves  be used then for detection ?

Comment: Same comment as for other answer: it's not the hypersonic speed itself but rather a large number of parameters (altitude, active steering) attributed to a given missile design that matter.